# Dynamically changing the foreground color of an Image in Android Java (retaining the alpha transparency)

Tags: java, android, image, bitmapimage

I have an image of red ball with transparent background. I want to change the color of ball to many other colors programatically without affecting the background i.e. background shall remain transparent. How this can be achieved in Android?

Comment: Your query is very generic. There are multiple ways to do this, however without knowing the actual use-case it's difficult to mention the *correct* way to do this. Could you elaborate more about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: In the game screen, many balls of different colors will pop up. Instead of using multiple images , I want to use one image and modify its color on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Bitmap` class to modify your image in this way, such as using the `setPixel()` method. You just need to make sure that the color still has its alpha set to transparent.

Refer to the `Color` documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) for defining colors with their RGB and Alpha channels (you want to keep the alpha values of each pixel, and only change the RGB values). Also refer to the `Bitmap` documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)

Comment: do you mean i just need to specify rgb not alpha, which will be taken from the image data itself ?

Comment: Yes. You need to get the color of each pixel using `getPixel()`, change only the red/green/blue values (keeping the alpha at its current value), and then call `setPixel()` with the new color. If the alpha value isn't changed, the transparency should stay the same as the original image.

Comment: Is this method resource consuming, because i will have to manipulate the image 5-10 times per second.

Comment: its not resource consuming, its just time consuming. What I would suggest is, before you start the game, create all the images programmatically and store then as variables. When you want to change the color of the ball, just point to the different variable. Creating the colored balls before you start the game means that you wont suffer any performance impact when you go to use the recolored images.

Comment: If you're calling it 5-10 times a second, you want it to be as quick to change as possible, so you want to keep a variable to the already-recolored balls and just swap between them, which is much faster than needing to recolor the ball 5-10 times a second

Comment: do i really need to worry about time consumption, if image is 100px x 100px ?

Comment: 100x100 shouldn't be too time consuming, but it'll still be slower than recalling an image from a variable (memory). Most games on any system (PC, gaming consoles, mobile) will have a 'loading' time at the beginning of the game to load all the images into memory so that it can access them quicker - even though its not critical for a 100x100 image, it'd still probably be good practice.

Comment: It would also be beneficial to store them in memory if you're going to be re-using the colors over and over again. That way, if you're changing the ball to 'green', you only have to calculate it once, rather than calculating it every time you want a 'green' ball.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18856/discussion-between-ashni-goyal-and-watto-studios)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
//Bitmap bmp
//int color 
int[] pixels = new int[bmp.getWidth() * bmp.getHeight()];
bmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, bmp.getWidth(), 0, 0,
            bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
pixels[i] &= color;
}
Bitmap newBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(),
bmp.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
newBmp.setPixels(pixels, 0, newBmp.getWidth(), 0, 0, newBmp.getWidth(), newBmp.getHeight());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also achieve it by using [Frame Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame). Use different pictures of same ball image with different ball colors, and use frame animation to run the images as frames.If so, the colors of ball looks to be changing.